# How to sort tableview item top to bottom using coredata

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I'm trying to create a list of name in a tableView and I sorted it top to bottom and I'm using coreData to save all information but when I restart my app my tableView being sorted bottom to top instead of top to bottom.

I tried to use many other ways but getting so confused about it.

My coreData entinty "Person" and inside it I have "name"

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

var newList = [Person]()
var currentList = [Person]()
var myIndex = 0

class TableViewVC_SmartAccounting: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var txtField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var outAdd: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchData()
    newList = currentList
    searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    txtField.delegate = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    txtField.resignFirstResponder()
    print("RETURN")
    return true
}

func fetchData(){

    let fetchRequist: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let listFetched = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequist)
        currentList = listFetched
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print("Field to fetch an item", err)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return currentList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellVC_SmartAccounting
    cell.lblName.text = currentList[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        let person = currentList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        PersistenceService.context.delete(person)
        PersistenceService.saveContext()
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myIndex = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

func addPerson(){
    if txtField.text != ""{

        let person = Person(context: PersistenceService.context)
        person.name = txtField.text
        PersistenceService.saveContext()
       // currentList.append(person)
        currentList.insert(person, at: myIndex)
        view.endEditing(true)
        newList = currentList
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: myIndex, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)

       // tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: list.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }
    txtField.text = ""
    self.view.endEditing(true)


}

func setUpSearchBar() {
    searchBar.delegate = self
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    guard !searchText.isEmpty else {currentList = newList
        tableView.reloadData()
        return }
    currentList = newList.filter ({ (Person) -> Bool in
        (Person.name?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    })
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
}

@IBAction func btnAdd(_ sender: Any) {
    addPerson()
}
```

}

Comment: Add a `NSSortDescriptor` to the fetch request or – still better – use `NSFetchedResultsController` which handles the sorting automatically

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it works now but only when I input number but when I but name so it still comes down when I restart my app, but numbers still write order.

Comment: Core Data saves records always unordered. If you want a custom order you have to add an index attribute and sort the records by index

Comment: If you see my code above. do you mean "myIndex"

Comment: Basically yes. But the index must be also an attribute of the Core Data entity (like `name`)

Comment: `person.index = Int32(newList.count)`

`let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Person.index), ascending: true)`

`fetchRequist.sortDescriptors = [sort]`

Comment: I create a new attribute called index, but I think I miss understand how to do because still doesn't work and creating empty item everytime I launch the app

Comment: This is not sufficient. The indexes must be unique. For example lets assume you have 4 records and you are going to insert a new record at index 2. You have to insert the object and then reindex the array (index 3 becomes index 4 and index 2 becomes index 3). You are responsible to keep the indexes unique and in the right order.

Comment: could you please try to show me based on my code where should I make changes?

Comment: I wrote an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the `Person` entity add an attribute `index` of type `Int32`
- In the controller add a method to reindex `currentList` and save the context

  ```
  func reindex()
  {
      for (index, person) in currentList.enumerated() {
          person.index = Int32(index)
      }
      PersistenceService.saveContext()
   }
  ```
- In `fetchData` add a sort descriptor

  ```
  fetchRequist.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "index", ascending: true)]
  ```
- After inserting an object reindex the array

  ```
  let person = Person(context: PersistenceService.context)
  person.name = txtField.text
  person.index = Int32(myIndex)
  currentList.insert(person, at: myIndex)
  let indexPath = IndexPath(row: myIndex, section: 0)
  tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
  reindex()
  view.endEditing(true)
  newList = currentList
  ```
- And after deleting an object reindex the array, too

  ```
  if editingStyle == .delete {
      let person = currentList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
      PersistenceService.context.delete(person)
      self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
      reindex()
  }
  ```